# Value of the matrix of 2nd order partial derivatives of the quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, quadratic-forms

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Define $$Q(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}
x & y & z \\
\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y  \\
z 
\end{pmatrix}$$
for $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$.
Then what is the value of the matrix of 2nd order partial derivatives of the quadratic form?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the expression for $Q(x, y, z)$? It should just come to a quadratic in terms of $x, y, z$, and should be relatively easy to partially differentiate.

Comment: I dont know the meaning of pd of quadratic?

Comment: The expression $Q(x, y, z)$ should simplify down to a scalar (or more precisely, a $1 \times 1$ matrix, but we treat it like a scalar). That is, it's just like any other real-valued function of $3$ variables. If you can partially differentiate something like $R(x, y, z) = x^2 + 3y^2 - z^2 + 2xy - xz$, then you can differentiate $Q(x, y, z)$.

Comment: @user771918 please link me to a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align*}
Q(x, y, z) &= \begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x + 2y \\ -2z \\ z \end{pmatrix} \\
&= x(x + 2y) + y(-2z) + z^2 \\
&= x^2 + z^2 + 2xy - 2yz.
\end{align*}
We can now differentiate these partially with respect to $x, y, z$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} &= 2x + 2y \\
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} &= 2x - 2z \\
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} &= 2z - 2y.
\end{align*}
Differentiating again,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2} &= 2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y^2} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z^2} &= 2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y \partial x} &= 2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x \partial z} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z \partial x} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y \partial z} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z \partial y} &= -2.
\end{align*}
As a matrix, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x \partial z} \\ \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y \partial z} \\ \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial z^2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$